# Azure Runbook - No such parameter. Use AZ instead?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I want to set the VCore setting of an SQL elastic pool using Azure automation, and have successfully used the command

```
Set-AzSqlElasticPool
```

on the terminal.
However on the Powershell workflow, the appropriate command seems to be

```
Set-AzureRmSqlElasticPool
```

The issue is that this command does not seem to support the -VCore parameter. Even though it says it does in version 6, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/set-azurermsqlelasticpool?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

How can I either set the Powershell version, or use the

```
Set-AzSqlElasticPool
```

command instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have control over which commands your workflow will have access under the "modules" settings on your automation account blade.

Probably, your automation account only has the default modules, which includes AzureRM.SQL module version 1.0.3. [Check here all the default modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#default-modules)

So, you can either update this module to version 6, or install [az.sql module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/?view=azps-4.7.0) that contains the function you used in your terminal `Set-AzSqlElasticPool`